# How to call a action creator in a functional component with react-redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I'm learning react-redux. I am struggling a bit with the use of redux in functional components. How do I call an action from a functional component. I have seen some tutorials that use react hooks. Which makes sense to me. But these tutorials call action types and not functions that create action types.

My case:

**Wrapping container:** Im passing from a wrapping container component that manages all data  the necassary props down to the `LoadedNavbar` function:

```
<LoadedNavbar isAuthenticated = {isAuthenticated} profile = {profile} />
```

**Functional Component**: A Navbar with a button to log out. The logout action should be called in the functional component.How do i make the action creator `logout` available in this function?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { logout } from "../../../../actions/auth";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export function LoadedNavbar (props) {

    const {isAuthenticated, profile} = props


  return (

   <div> 

   <button onClick={this.props.logout} className="nav-link btn btn-info btn-sm text-light">Logout</button> 

   </div>

   )
}
```

**Action**

```
// LOGOUT USER
export const logout = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
  axios
    .post(apiBase + "/auth/logout/", null, tokenConfig(getState))
    .then(res => {
      dispatch({
        type: LOGOUT_SUCCESS
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status));
    });
};
```

**Reducer**

```
export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOGOUT_SUCCESS:
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are two ways to dispatch actions from functional components:

- Using `mapDispatachToProps` function with `connect` higher order component, same as in class based components.

  For details of how to use `mapDispatchToProps` along with `connect` to dispatch actions, see: [React Redux - Connect: Dispatching Actions with mapDispatchToProps](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch)
- Using `useDispatch` hook provided by `react-redux`.

  If you want to use this hook, then you need to import it from the `react-redux` package. This hook returns a function that can be used to dispatch actions.

  **Example:**

  ```
  import React from "react";
  import { logout } from "../../../../actions/auth";
  import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";

  function LoadedNavbar (props) {
      ...

      const dispatch = useDispatch();

      const handleClick = () => {
          dispatch(logout());
      }

      return (
         <div> 
           <button onClick={handleClick}>Logout</button> 
         </div>
      )
  }
  ```

  For details of hooks provided by `react-redux`, see [React Redux - Hooks](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks)